# How to display individual images by each date in google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel2

I am new to google earth engine and not so familiar with javascript. I want to display the cleared images (B4,B3,B2 bands) of Sentinel 2 by each dates in layers (each layer represent each date). The code is shown as below, but always get error 'no Band 4, constant band'. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

```
var lakes=table.geometry();
Map.centerObject(lakes, 15);

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var start = ee.Date('2015-06-20');
var finish = ee.Date('2018-06-01');

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate(start, finish)
                  .filterBounds(lakes)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

function addImage(imageL) { // display each image in collection
  var id = imageL.id;
  var image = ee.Image(imageL.id);
  Map.addLayer(image.select(['B4','B3','B2']).clip(lakes),rgbVis,id)
}

collection.evaluate(function(collection) {  // use map on client-side
  print(collection.features);
  collection.features.map(addImage);
})
```